# CodeIgniter, Get URL Result

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have php code in my VIEW like this :

```
<tbody>
<?php $i=1; foreach ($kelas_kuliah as $val): ?>
<tr>
    <td>
        <?php site_url('/admin/cdtkelas_kuliah/get_id_sms/'.$val->kdpsttrak);?>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php $i++; endforeach; ?>
```

it should return value like this :

> 7678c279-0656-4458-968e-9a1c5a8b0fdb

this is my CONTROLLER :

```
    public function get_id_sms($prmkode_prodi){
    $client = new SoapClient($this->wsdl);

    $username = '******';
    $password = '******';

    $token = $client->GetToken($username, $password);

    $prmtable  = 'sms';
    $prmfilter = "kode_prodi like '".$prmkode_prodi."'";

    $get_record = $client->GetRecord($token,$prmtable,$prmfilter);

    echo $get_record->result->id_sms;
}
```

but when I ran it, it shows nothing, why is that ? thanks.

Comment: Are you getting any error

Comment: it shows nothing, of course it is an error.

Comment: What error are you getting

Comment: It should return value type of string, but I got nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shows nothing because you missed `echo` . See the updated code

```
<td>
   <?php echo site_url('/admin/cdtkelas_kuliah/get_id_sms/'.$val->kdpsttrak);?>
         ^^^^^
</td>
```

**Edited:** Try this if you want values only

```
<td>
   <?php echo $val->kdpsttrak;?>
</td>
```

Comment: If I add "echo" it will show the URL itself, what I want is the result of the function.